# inheritLogging=true how and were logs can be found?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm running local Dataflow instance. 
I want to centralize all apps logs as described in reference document.

With property `deployer.*.local.inheritLogging=true`, I can see in deployer log:

`[...]Deploying app with deploymentId test-time-to-log.time instance 0. 
Logs will be inherited.`

**Question is: where can I see those logs?**

I have custom working dir, but no logs there.

I have deployer log stored as file, but again, no apps logs there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the [ref. guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_log_redirect), the `inheritLogging` support provides the ability to redirect the stdout/stderr output to the parent process. The logs aren't persistent in this case, though. They are streamed to the parent process builder.

The primary goal of this support is to help with incremental development/troubleshooting when using the Local-server.

Here's the [snippet](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-local/blob/master/spring-cloud-deployer-local/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/deployer/spi/local/LocalAppDeployer.java#L192-L201) from the Local Deployer that determines the downstream process-builder action based on the `inheritLogging` identifier.

If you have to capture the logs, perhaps you could use an Application Monitoring tooling or pipe the content to a file from when you start the Local-server process *(eg: java -jar spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar > foo.txt)*.

Comment: Got it. I thought that everything will be logged to file. Thanks.